# ¿como cambio el valor de una etiqueta en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

hola buenas el problema que tengo es que no puedo actualizar el valor de una etiqueta siendo que es una lectura de un block de notas al cambiar el valor del block de notas no cambia este sino al reiniciar el programa

```py
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Tk

ventana=Tk()
d1=IntVar()
archivo = open('d1.txt','r')
d1=float(archivo.read())
etiqueta2 = Label(ventana,text=(d1,"%"))
etiqueta2.place(x=0,y=70)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Solo quiero actualizar el dato cuando la variable del bloc de notas cambie eh probado con `textvariable` pero no me arroja ningún número

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodrigo, prueba esta solución, y nos cuentas si te es de utilidad.

```
from tkinter import Tk, IntVar, Label, Button
import threading
import time

ventana = Tk()
continuar = True

def actualizarValor():
  while continuar:
    with open('d1.txt', 'r') as archivo:
      etiqueta["text"] = archivo.read()
    time.sleep(1)
  etiqueta["text"] = "He terminado"

def detenerLectura():
  global continuar
  continuar = False

etiqueta = Label(ventana, text="0")
boton = Button(ventana, text="Detener lectura", command=detenerLectura)
etiqueta.place(x=0, y=70)
boton.place(x=100, y=70)


hilo = threading.Thread(target=actualizarValor)
hilo.start()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Con el módulo **threading**, se ejecuta la función **actualizarValor**, de forma independiente del resto del programa:

```
hilo = threading.Thread(target=actualizarValor)
```

Luego, **actualizarValor** entra en un ciclo infinito, mientras que *continuar* sea True, abriendo, leyendo y cerrando el archivo, para actualizar el atributo **text** del widget Label:

```
etiqueta["text"] = archivo.read()
```

Agregué además, el módulo **time**, para usar **sleep()** y crear una pausa de 1 segundo entre cada lectura.

Una vez que lo hayas probado, nos cuentas si esto responde a tu pregunta o si faltan cosas.

Comment: gracias amigo me ayudaste me sirvio solo necesitaba esa visualizacion